# found a function in a file and after select it to do operation in my program matlab

Tags: matlab, function, select, call

I created this function to browse all the functions stored in a file and now I want to select my function in my main program how can I select it

This is my function:

```
function testMode(i)
a=dir('H_*.m');
if exist('i','var')
    if isempty(i)
        z={a.name}';
        [selection,ok]=listdlg('ListString',z,'SelectionMode','single');
        if ok
            i=find(selection,1,'first');
        end
    end
    nom=a(i).name;
    nom=nom(1:end-2);
    disp(nom)
else
    disp('fonction a un argument')
end
```

Comment: are you asking how to call your function in your main?

Comment: yes i want to know how can i call it

Comment: your function code should start with something like function result = testMode(i). Save this file in your project path, in your main, simply call it by doing testMode (input)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will have the name of the function as a string.  To call that function, you can either use `feval`, or you can convert the string to a function handle and call that.

```
result = feval(nom, argument1);
```

or

```
fcn = str2func(nom);
fcn(argument1);
```

The latter should be preferred, as the conversion can be done once and the function handle re-used after that, and because the calling syntax is exactly the same as calling a regular function.

For more information on function handles, see `doc function_handle`.

Also, for a different approach, see this document: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/localfunctions.html.  If you can create your "menu" of functions as local functions in a single file, this approach could be very clean and simple, as it will directly give you a cell array of function handles of all of those subfunctions.  From there, you can get easily get the function name for display using `functions` command.